# Retrieving a Django form field value using AJAX

Tags: ajax, django

For each fact in facts, there is a form where you can upvote or downvote the fact.

Further explanation is found below.

Template and Form code are listed below respectively:

*template*

```
<ul>
        {% for fact in facts %}
            <form method='POST' action="{% url 'facts:list' fact.pk %}" id="list_vote">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="vote" />
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

*forms.py* code:

```
VOTE_CHOICES = [
    (1, 'upvote'),
    (0, 'downvote')
]


class Vote(forms.Form):
    vote = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VOTE_CHOICES,
                             widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'vote'}))
```

For each fact in `models.Fact.objects.all()`, there is a form,  which consists of radio buttons of 2 inputs (upvote, downvote), created for this specific fact. What I'm now doing is basically Django 101: getting the value of the fact that is being voted and update its model accordingly in the views.

What I want to do is retrieve the value of this specific fact using **AJAX** and update the model accordingly **without leaving/refreshing the page**

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you.  I just went through a lot of learning on AJAX and how to connect to DJANGO templates.   You'll need some javascript on your template to make the AJAX connection.

Below is a generic AJAX javascript connector function I abstracted from my recent work.  It needs both prototype.js http://prototypejs.org/ and jquery.js https://jquery.com/download/ imported into your template to run.  Also requires a jQuery noconflict statement to allow both to run at the same time.

Basically all you need to do is pass the AJAXconnector function I wrote your data in a {'myvariable' : 'myvalue', 'myvariable2' : 'myvalue2'} format and destination is the url (in string format) which points to your views.py processing function to handle the AJAX data and return a reply.  Also its important to use a local (relative) link as your destination.

I did a little tutorial on my blog if you want to check it out too - it walks through the AJAX connection on the template (javascript side) and the server (python side) http://www.americantechnocracy.com/getArticle/4/

the code I'm posting below also has some more description at:
http://www.americantechnocracy.com/getArticle/9

Let me know if you have questions.  Happy to answer.

```
// Requires prototype.js
// Requires jquery.js

// enable use of both prototype and jquery
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// get the CSRF Token
        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

// function for AJAX communication of data from Template to View.py and back
    function AJAXConnector(parameters, destination) {
                // myParameters = {'targetPK': pk, };
                myParameters = parameters;
                csrfHeader = {'X-CSRFToken' : csrftoken};
                // This is the start of my AJAX Function
                new Ajax.Request(destination, {
                    method: 'post', parameters: myParameters, requestHeaders: csrfHeader,
                    onSuccess: function (transport) {
                        var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
                        data = response.evalJSON();
                    },
                    onFailure: function () {
                        alert('Something went wrong...');
                    }
                });
            }
```